How to copy attributes to new line using XSLT
Using XSL, I am trying to figure out a way to copy each attribute to new line. But I couldn't get a solution. Can anyone please let me know how to do that using XSL.
Input XML:
<Pane attr1="value1" attr2="value2" attr3="value3">
    <children>
        <title>A</title>
    </children>
</Pane>

Output XML:
<Pane attr1="value1" 
      attr2="value2" 
      attr3="value3">
    <children>
        <title>A</title>
    </children>
</Pane>


Whitespace between XML attributes is insignificant.  No conformant XML processing software will care about it, and neither should you or your code.  You might be able to influence it via implementation-specific serializers of some XSLT processors, but again, you just shouldn't bother.

I think Saxon in its commercial editions (PE and EE) allows you to set an proprietary saxon:line-length output property, if you set it very low I think it will put each attribute on a line of its own on serializing. But in general a particular output formatting might be best handled by some custom serialization code in the platform/XML stack you are using.

IMO just BaseX 11.0 and later supports such functionality. Check it out indent-attributes setting: https://docs.basex.org/main/Serialization

See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html: saxon:line-length : "Default value 80. With the XML output method, attributes are output on a new line if they would otherwise extend beyond this column position.".

It's essentially a feature of the serializer you're looking for, not a feature of XSLT.

Here is BaseX 11.0 and later solution that indents XML attributes. Every single attribute will be on a new line.
The indent-attributes parameter does the trick.
It is documented here: Serialization
Input XML
<Pane attr1="value1" attr2="value2" attr3="value3">
   <children>
      <title>A</title>
   </children>
</Pane>

XQuery
declare variable $base_dir as xs:string := 'e:\Temp\IndentAttributes\';

for $x at $i in collection($base_dir)
return file:write($base_dir || "output_" || $i || ".xml"
  , $x
  , map {'method': 'xml', 'indent': 'yes', 'indent-attributes': 'yes'})

Output XML
<Pane attr1="value1"
      attr2="value2"
      attr3="value3">
   <children>
      <title>A</title>
   </children>
</Pane>


Thanks for the solution. I think i missed to mention that I am not using BaseX. I am working with plain java code to convert one xml file using xsl.

BaseX has HTTP listener. So you can make REST HTTP call from your Java code and leverage Service oriented approach

This is not something you can control through XSLT (it may be possible by configuring your XSLT processor).
A convenient way to get the wanted result is to run the output through the Tidy command line tool, using the -indent-attributes option. Tidy is included with macOS and Linux, and AFAIK also available for Windows and Java.
